# Cannot access my site ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: http, https, dns, cloudflare

yesterday at 2:25 AM I got mail from Cloudflare “The name servers for [pro-cs-is.com](https://www.pro-cs-is.com/) no longer point to Cloudflare”, I checked godady DNS and found that DNS returned to the origin DNS even though I didn’t change it! , I returned it to cloudflare DNS a few hours ago but I still cannot access my website and always I get this error “**The Mixed content tests failed. Please be sure that you can connect to your site over SSL and try again.
Error Returned: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**”

Comment: Are you managing your own server?

Comment: no, I just using Cloudflare DNS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after I contacted with Cloudflare support, they said

> "Flexible mode works by not encrypting traffic to and from your origin and Cloudflare. Because your origin is forcing https and the request is then redirected to Cloudflare where Cloudflare again tries to send the same http request, an infinite loop is occurring."
>   
> the solution of this issue is :
>
> - enable Full or Full Strict mode
> - Remove the redirect at your origin and implement the same behavior via Cloudflare page rule.